# Application of Tchebychev-inequality

Tags: probability

There are $100$ passengers on a plane. Every single person's "weight" (mass) $X$ has an expected value of $70$ kg and a standard deviation of $10$ kg.
The weight $Y$ of their luggage has an expected value of $20$ kg and a standard deviation of $10$ kg. The plane is not allowed to take off if the weight $W$ of passengers and luggage together exceeds $9\,420$ kg.

Using the Tchebychev-inequality, find an upper bound of the probability that the plane is not allowed to take off.

---

When I compute the variance of the total weight, I obtain:
$$\sigma^2(W)=\sigma^2(100X+100Y)=100^2\sigma^2(X)+100^2\sigma^2(Y)=2\,000\,000$$
and an expected value for $W$ of
$$\mathbb{E}(W)=100\cdot 70 + 100 \cdot 20=9\,000.$$

Hence, for all $a>0$,

$$\mathbb{P}\{W-\mathbb{E}(W)\geq a\}\leq\mathbb{P}\{|W-\mathbb{E}(W)|\geq a\}\leq \frac{\sigma^2(W)}{a^2},$$

where the Tchebychev-inequality is used in the last step.

Thus, for $a=420$, we obtain:

$$\mathbb{P}\{W\geq 9\,420\}=\mathbb{P}\{W-\mathbb{E}(W)\geq 420\}\leq \frac{\sigma^2(W)}{420^2}=\frac{5\,000}{441}\approx 11.3.$$

It is clear that this upper bound is useless. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake lies in the following:
$$
W = 100X + 100Y
$$
$100X$ is $100$ times the weight of a single person. The weight of $100$ people should be the sum of $100$ i.i.d. $X$, or:
$$
W = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i + \sum_{i=1}^{100} Y_i
$$

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you.